# How to Center a group of images with links

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for my website and I am trying to center the images on the webpages

```
<ul class="">
        <a href="https://www.github.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/github.png" border="0" alt="Code" class="">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/linkedin.png" border="0" alt="Connect" class="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/twitter.png" border="0" alt="Twitter">
        </a>
      </ul>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 400px;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
}
```

What would I need to do to center all three image links on my website?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<ul style="display:block;margin:0px auto;">
  ///tags
</ul>
```

it will justify the ul tag.

```
<ul style="width:100%;display:block;text-align:center;">
   ///tags
 </ul>
```

it will justify the content of the ul tags

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nj2uU/1/)

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;  /*  added  */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Another quick question, how would I add some vertical padding on the images?

Comment: @user2604504 use `padding: 10px 0;` for images

Answer (score 0):

```
    ul{
    margin: 0 auto; /* For hate it at the center*/
    padding: 0;
    width: aWidthToTheDiv; /* You could set it to 100% or an value as 800px (example) */
}
```

And done :)

This should work, also you could add a tag as "text-align:center;" but this is gonna keep all the text at the center and probably you want to have it in other alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't used `<li>` tag along with `<ul>`

I recommend you to use to `<p>` tag.

This might be funny.But its so simple and you dont need to do any additional styling.

All you need to do is add `text-align:center`

TRY THIS -> [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nj2uU/4/)